# Synology DSM 6.0 SSH - command ether-wake no longer working

Tags: ssh, nas, synology

Since I upgraded to DSM 6.0, I no longer have the ability to 'wake on lan devices in my network.
I used to do an SSH from a remote computer and ran following command:

```
ether-wake -i eth0 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

This would send a WOL package to my desktop. Yet when I try and run this command after the update I get following error:

```
~ash: ether-wake: command not found
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They replaced the command with:

```
synonet --wake [MAC address] eth0
```

or if you have a bond:

```
synonet --wake [MAC address] bond0
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you have a source?

Comment: Damnit, took me hours to figure that out! Thanks.